# Adding a new column using dplyr by searching through the data set

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a new column to a data frame but am running into some issue as my train of thought does not seem to work.

My question is based on the countries-aggregated.csv from [this](https://github.com/datasets/covid-19/tree/master/data) GitHub source.

Taking a look at the head it shows:

[image]

What I would like to do is add a new column describing the new Deaths for that day. This is calculated by taking the Deaths of that day minus the Deaths of the day before.

My idea was to create a copy and use that as a reference. Like so:

```
tb_copy <- tb
tb <- tb %>% mutate(newDeaths = tb_copy %>% filter(tb_copy$Country == tb$Country) %>% filter(tb_copy$Date == tb$Yesterday) %>% pull(Deaths))
```

This does not work, not all countries record death toll at a daily basis. For example the Netherlands seems to be in the data set every other day. How could I take this into consideration and make it so it subtracts not the amount of Deaths from the day before but the amount from the last insert for that country?

The error thrown using the above code is:

```
Error: Column `newDeaths` must be length 175 (the number of rows) or one, not 0
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.factor", "==.Date") for "=="
```

*Edit: I had to edit the code in this question as I found a mistake in it that made it run without throwing an error.*

Comment: Please edit to add data using `dput(head(df,n))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date` is a factor, you should convert it to Date class first, `arrange` the data by `Country` and `Date`, `group_by` `Country` and subtract values using `lag`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%
 arrange(Country, Date) %>% 
 group_by(Country) %>%
 mutate(New_deaths = Deaths - lag(Deaths))
```

Comment: I got a lecture in a bit. Will try this soon as it ends.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, we can do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(Country, as.IDate(Date)), New_deaths := Deaths -
          shift(Deaths), by = Country]
```